# how to make timeupdate event fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure how to add the timeupdate event to this code to get it to run properly.  I have been looking online and have been stuck for some time
I have
(function($){

```
  $.fn.playerConnect = function(player){


        var transcriptElements = this;


        player.onTime(function(evt){


}; 
                var time =  ''; replace the empty quotes with your code
                console.log(time);
```

I was not sure whether to add "timeUpdate" into the quote marks, or not
But if I tried I got an error saying that the event handler had an error.
I really need this done soon and any help is much appreciated im almost prepared to pay someone for help im so stuck

Comment: You really should specify where this javascript comes from, because most of us wont event know this is about jwplayer!

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete, have you tried removing the authors annotation from it... ("replace the empty quotes with your code")?
Please provide a proper code snippet if you want us to help you. Also mention what libraries you're using.

Comment: Can you explain what you're expecting the code to do? I.e. what is the end result

Comment: code shown is far too fragmented for anyone to do much  with